# Why do I get BPA error "Servers in Failover Clusters Must Have a Hyper-V Replica Broker Configured"?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster

I configured a Hyper-V Failover Cluster with two nodes and one domain controller. Cluster-Aware Updating is enabled.

The BPA shows the following error:

> To Participate in Replication, Servers in Failover Clusters Must Have a Hyper-V Replica Broker Configured.
>   <sub>Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12798.hyper-v-to-participate-in-replication-servers-in-failover-clusters-must-have-a-hyper-v-replica-broker-configured.aspx</sub>

I don't understand why BPA is showing that error. I don't use and have not configured replication.

```
VMName                     ReplicationState
------                     ----------------
xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx                 Disabled
xxxxxxxx                           Disabled
xxxxxx                             Disabled
xxxxxxxx                           Disabled
xxxxxxxxxx                         Disabled
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx                     Disabled
xxxxxxxxxxx                        Disabled
xxxx-xx                            Disabled
xxxx-xxx                           Disabled
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx            Disabled
xxxxxxxxxx                         Disabled
xxxxxxxxx                          Disabled
xxxxxxxxxx                         Disabled
```

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why that is considered an error rather than informational but the gist of it is, if you plan to use Hyper-V Replica then you need to configure a Hyper-V Replica Broker. If you don't plan on using Hyper-V Replica then  you can ignore that error or exclude it from the BPA results so that you don't see it again. If you're not using Hyper-V Replica then this error has no impact on the operation of Hyper-V or the Failover Cluster.

Comment: I know the BPA has some quirks, but in all cases I know, the misleading notifications are warnings or informations and not errors. Because it's an error, I believe something actually makes the BPA think I have configured Hyper-V Replica. So ignoring it is not an option unless I know for sure that I can. Thanks for the input, though.

Comment: Just to be sure, I ran the BPA on a fresh Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V Failover Cluster before I posted this answer and got the same error. I do not have Hyper-V Replica setup or configured in any way.

Comment: I have two more people validating your claim. I was hoping there were some proper way to deal with that, despite setting up a broker to just never use it. Obviously there isn't. Since you were the first to respond, you get the bounty. But thanks to everyone for their good advice.

Answer (score 2):

The "issue" you have is with a "result" of the BPA, which in fact is "only" an analyzer for best practices.

It is not really an error which impacts your production environment.

If you are using replication (I know you are not) then the "result" from BPA should be actioned.

If you are not using replication (as in your case) the "result" from BPA can be ignored.

This is known and documented in a wiki, here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12798.hyper-v-to-participate-in-replication-servers-in-failover-clusters-must-have-a-hyper-v-replica-broker-configured.aspx

If a wiki from social.technet is not "authoritative" enough for you, which I can understand as this would be open to edits, then I would believe the only route for an authoritative answer is to open a case with Microsoft Support Services to get that answer.

My advice here is to ignore the result.

HTH,
Edwin.

Comment: Since joeqwerty responded first, I like to grant him the bounty. But I really appreciated your response and your advice.

Answer (score 2):

As Edwin stated, it's a tool that isn't always correct. The BPA is best viewed as a tool for quickly gathering information and presenting it to you. The real power knows in how to interpret what it has gathered. If you know that you're not using Hyper-V Replica, then you know to ignore the "error" about the replica broker. Early users of this tool learned many moons ago that "best practices" sometimes weren't "best practice" :)

Comment: I see something odd in the BPA every other day. All above the misleading and bugged "srv.sys" error that people complain about all the time since the beginning of Server 2012 and maybe earlier. I would love if Microsoft would care a little more about the BPA as it could be such a powerfool advisor/tool.